# Oracle Function not retrieving data to Spotfire quickly

Tags: oracle, spotfire

I am using an Oracle function to retrieve data into Spotfire with a single input parameter. I get the output for the function in PL/SQL Developer in around 90 secs but when i try to open the same function added in Spotfire directly as a fucntion or added as an Information Link it is in loading state forever. Is there anything i can do retreive data in the same amount of time as the PL/Developer tool. In either case the calculation is in-DB and i dont know what might have gone wrong. I just got the output once in Spotfire, and not able to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **almost never** going to beat the query time in a DB IDE / Developer Tool. There's just more that has to happen when you are consuming the data into Spotfire. First, the exact same execution has to happen on the DB side. While in PL/SQL Developer this is the end of the steps. When loading into Spotfire there are more steps (conversion, loading into memory, etc).

What could also be slowing down your load time is transformations, calculated columns, low RAM / CPU availability on the Spotfire DB Server, network bandwidth between your Oracle DB and the Spotfire DB, and so on...

So theoretically your problem could be represented with something like:

***Normal Query Time*** + Network Latency + Resource Limitations + Spotfire Transformations + Other files being loaded in the analysis + unknowns...

Comment: i get it but i use functions for other and they are comparatively faster. Should i change the batch and fetch size in IL. Also since this is a in-DB calculation there wont be much memory usage in Spotfire. The Function i used is complex but the output just 24 rows.

Comment: @direwolf  that could be an issue but I doubt it with your small data set that's being returned. You could cache the IL as well so that follow on calls don't have to be recalculated

Comment: I am giving input with Data On Demand, so each user will give different inputs. Caching is not an option for me

Comment: @direwolf  that is understandable. Are the potential parameters set to a few options or could there be hundreds of possibilities?

Comment: For the report i need its just one input, but its a date. I ran the report again and there was som error in Spotfire. So replaced the IL and now it works fine. But want to find why initially it took so much time

Comment: That's odd. perhaps some sort of IL corruption. It'd be hard to diagnose without being able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Yeah i know. When i opened the report to check, i got error as that function as not available, but separately i ran the Function in Spotfire and in Oracle and it gave o/p fast.